# FB.getLoginStatus returns connected all the time

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, passport.js

Trying to run a FQL query and print out the results only when the user is logged in (login form is on the same page).

Relevant code -

```
FB.init({
appId: '451320528308299',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
channelUrl: 'http://URL.COM/channel', // channel.html file
oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.multiquery',
        queries: {
            'query1': 'select status_id, message from status where uid = me()',
            'query2': 'select user_id, object_id from like where object_id in (#query1)'
        }
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
} else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
}
```

Above code runs in `$(document).ready` and prints output to console even if not logged in. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** - Turns out I'm logged on to Facebook.com (but logged out of my app). I'm calling `req.logout()` (using Passport middleware with ExpressJS).

Comment: Facebook logout is not happening .. Read the docs for the same